# How to pull dynamic data from a javascript-based website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to pull the data from a site like [this](http://www.globalpoker.com). The idea is to build a Google Chrome extension that can pull the data and maybe inject some javascript into the browser with statistics of each players action frequencies while the table is open.

I have noticed that if you use the Google devtools and 'inspect' a table while it is running, that the data changes with every players action. This is the data that would be useful to retrieve. What is the best way to do accomplish this task? Would it be to build a Javascript Chrome extension? Is this project too complicated for someone beginning in Javascript but has a few months in Python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a [Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) with a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that uses [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Too broad question. Make research if you have any questions ask here.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. Exactly what I was asking. Tim, to clarify I did research before asking the question but the research does not always turn up the best information.  In this instance, if I had not asked this question, I would not know about these specific modules. Everyone that leaves comments like "too broad" or "be more specific" are not helping the community. Please try to be more helpful or do not respond to future posts of mine. Thank you.